# Windows C++: absolute memory address to read system time from?

Tags: c++, windows, time, system

I'm trying to find system time without needing any function/system calls. I seem to remember Windows having an absolute address that a giant struct sits in, which is constantly updated with various system info including time...but google isn't giving me anything...did I imagine this or is it a thing?

Comment: likely any of this an internal windows implementation detail and can change from version to version

Comment: It’s still there, but why?

Comment: You might want to elaborate your use case, to avoid a regular system call. Looks like an xy-problem to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`KUSER_SHARED_DATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/ns-ntddk-kuser_shared_data) @ 0x7FFE0000 ([its evolution](http://terminus.rewolf.pl/terminus/structures/ntdll/_KUSER_SHARED_DATA_combined.html)) but the documented functions just read from there anyway so all you gain is the possibility of your application breaking in the next version of Windows.

###### Further reading

- [Getting OS Information - The KUSER_SHARED_DATA Structure](https://osm.hpi.de/wrk/2007/08/getting-os-information-the-kuser_shared_data-structure/)
- [Randomizing the KUSER_SHARED_DATA Structure on Windows](https://msrc.microsoft.com/blog/2022/04/randomizing-the-kuser_shared_data-structure-on-windows/) (gist: read-only version still available at the same address as it used to be *on x86-32 and x86-64*!)

Comment: It should go without saying that this struct has grown over time and probably never existed on Win9x. The kernel address is different and varies on 32 vs 64 bit.

Comment: Win9x doesn't trace its heritage back to NT, so you're right. But all consumer Windows versions since Windows 2000 and all server versions ever have been NT. Also, documented and undocumented functions alike typically read from there and/or the PEB. Alas, the PEB values can be faked, this seems to be mapped read-only into user space.